# Clarification about PrimeFaces Expression Language Injection

Tags: java, injection, el-injection

The PrimeFaces Expression Language Injection explained here:
http://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2016/02/rce-in-oracle-netbeans-opensource.html

Will happy for the clarification about the remediation:
Why not enough to filter all requests with `pfdrt=sc`?
Why need to ensure that `pfdrid` parameter longer than 16 bytes and Base64 encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just filter against requests containing `pfdrt=sc`, but that would break legitimate requests to that functionality which use streamed content. The exploit relies on being able to send more than 16 bytes of base64 encoded data to that particular functionality, in order to inject expression language.

As such, in order to allow legitimate requests to that functionality, but block malicious requests at the same time, you must filter requests which contain `pfdrt=sc` *and* which have a `pfdrid` parameter whose value is a base64 string representing more than 16 bytes of data.

Comment: Can you fix pftdrt to pfdrt ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo!